# image compression using lesser coefficients

Tags: image-processing

I am interested in finding the matlab code for performing a lossy compression of a 256x256 image i.e. 65536 coefficients using 1024 coefficients, i.e. by 1/64 of the original data. How will that be done using matlab? Is there a specific command for this purpose?

Comment: huh?  what do you want?  256x256 is pixels, right?  again, huh?

Comment: yes 256X256 are the pixels.I want to use 1024 coefficients to reconstruct the same image that requires 65536 coefficients for a two dimensional wavelet compression.is it possible?

Comment: You might be talking about DCT, is that right ?

Comment: See http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/discrete-cosine-transform.html for an exact example showing how to do that.

Comment: thanx alot mmgp u solved my problem.Now would you like to tell me the importance of decomposition levels while performing wavelet or dct compression. how many maximium levels of decomposition can be applied in 1024 coefficient reconstruction for the case of the above mentioned example?

Comment: Actually 'wcompress' command is ideal for this purpose. It serves the purpose best

Comment: Some coefficients/frequencies are more important than others.